# CSS Two borders. different height

Tags: html, css

I have a question, is it possible to do something like in attachment in pure css?

```
<h3 style="border-bottom:1px solid #515151"><span style="border-bottom:3px solid #0066b3">HEADER</span></h3>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
h3 {
    height:14px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

h3 > span {
 border-bottom: 5px solid blue;  
}
```

And your html

```
<h3><span>HEADER</span></h3>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yMe3/)

Comment: `h3 {
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #515151;
}

h3 > span {
 border-bottom: 5px solid #0066b3;  
}` This is enough? I look in IE, FF, Chrome and it is OK :)

Comment: @jachu Apparently yes :p

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example this should do it:

```
<style type="text/css">
  h3{
    border-bottom:1px solid #515151
  }
  span{
    border-bottom:3px solid #0066b3
  }
</style>
```

But for a real use you might wanna add some clases to your html elements to do a more specific targeting of css

Answer (score 0):

You could do that without any extra markup. By using pseudo-elements, for example. Like so:

```
h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    position: relative;
}

h2:before {
    height: 3px;
    width: 70px;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -2px;
    content: '';
}
```

See online: http://jsfiddle.net/46uqV/

Comment: The problem is that he will have to adjust the width if the text changes.

Comment: @Beterraba, yes, I agree. But it's unclear on the screen if it needs to be the same as the phrase...

Comment: Thanks, but I dont know width of blue bar. Bar width should be proportional to the text.

Comment: @user3257705, then my solution is not for you, I misunderstood you :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2D8c9/

```
<span class="outer">
    <span class="inner"></span>
    <span class="thinner-inner"></span>
</span>


.outer {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:black;

}
.inner {
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    top:5px;
    height:8px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index:2;
}
.thinner-inner {
    position:absolute;
    top:8px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    height:1px;
    z-index:1;
}
```